# Crystal report + c# date format

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

I have datetime var that I show him in Crystal report

I whant to see in short format (dd/mm/yyyy) - but I see him in Long (dd/mm/yyy hh:mm:ss)

what can i do ?

Answer (score 2):

You have to format the field in Crystal Reports editor. Right-click the field in design mode, and choose "Format" or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the CStr function to format the date as needed if this is going to be in a formula field. I believe the below would work, but didn't try it to be certain.

```
Cstr({field}, "dd/MM/yyyy")
```

Answer (score 0):

I use this method to format the date

```
ToText(Date ({Table.DATEField}),"MM/dd/yyyy")
```